# Find Node at DOMDocument by line number

Tags: php, domdocument

I load a .xml file into a DOMDocument and validate this with an .xsd file. After this i got some errors if the xml is not valide, with some line numbers. This works very fine.

Is it possible to move to this node by the line number. I need this to get mor information for my user to identify the problem.

Any Ideas to do this?

Regards
Juergen